# AAC m4a file corrupted while recording. Can anyone help me recover it?

Tags: audio, file, repair, recovery, aac-m4a

Recorded an important voice memo on iPhone application. After the recording was stopped, the phone's battery died and AAC file was corrupted. It is 8mb and should play for roughly 45 minutes but the play time shows it as having no length.

I do not have the hex editing ability to find the AAC headers and match them to a healthy file.

Is there anyone able to help? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/how-to-recover-audio-from-an-incomplete-or-corrupted-aac-m4a-file

Comment: Yes ffmpeg could help? any sample file or whole file you could provide?

Answer (score 1):

[How to fix corrupted voice memo (m4a) files](http://sysfrontier.com/en/2014/12/31/hello-world/) – I have not tried it by myself but according to a bunch of comments it works.

Comment: Tried FFMPEG on Windows CMD -- didn't work. Trying this method now. Will report back whether or not it works.

Comment: Works!!! Windows 10. I was able to recover interviews I recorded for a news story. Thanks for posting! :)